# Gulp Sass Compiles Only With Two Saves

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I've been trying to compile changes to @imports along with those to main SCSS files, and basically have this working.

The issue with my setup: To see changes, I must save files twice (irrespective of whether they're main files or imports). Ideas on this are greatly appreciated.

The directory structure is simply:

--> SCSS
--> SCSS/partials

Here are the relevant parts of my gulpfile:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var $    = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sync = require('browser-sync').create(); // create a browser sync instance.

var sassPaths = [
  'bower_components/foundation-sites/scss',
  'bower_components/motion-ui/src'
];

var paths = {
  'assets': 'assets',
  'dev': 'assets/styles/dev'
};

// DEV CSS

  gulp.task('dev-styles', function() {
    return gulp.src(['scss/**/*.scss', 'scss/*.scss'])
    .pipe($.sass({
      includePaths: sassPaths,
      outputStyles: 'expanded'
    })
      .on('error', $.sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie >=9']
    }))
    .pipe(rename({
      suffix: '.dev'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('paths.dev'));
  });


// DEFAULT WATCH

  gulp.task('default', function() {

    sync.init({
      injectChanges: true,
      proxy: 'localhost/basic-modx'
    });
 
 gulp.watch([ 'scss/**/*.scss', 'scss/*.scss' ], ['dev-styles']);
    gulp.watch([ 'scss/**/*.scss', 'scss/*.scss' ]).on('change', sync.reload);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your watches are set up oddly.  I suspect that the second which reloads the browser finishes before the first which actually transpiles the scss, so nothing has changed when the reload occurs.  Hence you have to hit save twice.

The better way from [browserSync documentation](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp/) is to have the reload at the end of your 'dev-styles' task like this:

```
gulp.task('dev-styles', function() {
   return gulp.src(['scss/**/*.scss', 'scss/*.scss'])
     .pipe($.sass({
        includePaths: sassPaths,
        outputStyles: 'expanded'
     })
    .on('error', $.sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
       browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie >=9']
    }))
    .pipe(rename({
      suffix: '.dev'
    }))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('paths.dev'));
   .pipe(sync.stream());
});
```

and get rid of the second gulp.watch statement.

Comment: Thank you -- I'd checked the browserSync documentation when this issue popped up and saw the incongruency of this setup, but also had used it on several projects without a problem. Anyway, now that the gulpfile adheres to the docs (!), all is well. Thanks again.